# Suppose we have the following identity: $(px + (1-p)y)^2 = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2.$ Find the minimum of $\max(A,B,C)$ over $0 \leq p \leq 1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have the following identity:

$$(px + (1-p)y)^2 = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2.$$
Find the minimum of $\max(A,B,C)$ over $0 \leq p \leq 1.$

---

First of all, what does $\text{max}(x,y,z)$ mean?  I'm confused with the max.  And also, how could I manipulate the given identity?  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\max(x,y,z)$ is just the largest of the 3 numbers $x,y,z$.

Comment: Hint: expand, equate coefficients, work out the $\text{max}$ as a function of $p$, then minimize it.

Comment: It may help to draw the graphs of $A,B,C$ vs $p$.